# What is the right tool to expand a large spring-type hose clamp?

Tags: tools, hose-clamp

My Touareg has the intake piping secured with a bunch of spring-type hose clamps.

I currently use a miniature C-clamp to expand them, but it is painfully slow, prone to slipping and access can be a problem at times.

[image: Spring Type Hose Clamp]

I have a pair of bent-nose pliers but they don't open wide enough. Before sinking funds into acquiring a bigger version of it, I was wondering if there is something that keeps the clamp expanded without keeping one hand busy.

So is there a more convenient, purpose-built tool for the job?

Comment: The first time you remove it, replace it with a jubilee clip.

Comment: @HandyHowie now where's the fun in that? :)

Comment: You should get yourself some bent long nose pliers. It's not the perfect tool for this job, but it will save you in many situations, including this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can use this tool to get the job done.**

They are called [Hose Clamp Pliers.](http://blog.toolsource.com/index.php/2010/04/toolsource-exclusive-meritool-hose-clamp-pliers/)

[image]

**This is not the right tool**

[image]

Comment: ROFL! Looks like a tool, but not the right one ;)

Comment: I had to uplevel my response since I was in competition with @paulster2

Comment: There is one benefit and one drawback of my solution over yours: drawback = the tool is more expensive; benefit = you can get to the clamp no matter what position it's in (which always seems to be out of the way where the pliers jaws cannot reach!). I still +1'd your answer if for no other reason than for the toolman.

Comment: @Paulster2  At the risk of sounding awkward.  I like your tool.  IT IS better and getting up into weird spots which is so frequently the case, right?  Upvote you for better tool.  I'd hate winning using my comedic skills....which are right up there with my nunchuck skills btw....so don't mess!  :-)

Answer (score 5):

If nothing else is available, I'd consider boot-pinch pliers, aka nail puller pliers, because the sharp edges will go under the lips and its going to be less likely to slip off than the C clamp.

Of course the right tool (as per other answers) would be much better, but for a once-off task then the right tool is quite expensive.

[image]

Comment: The trouble with such pliers is that the jaws are not wide enough to bite the spring, unless the pliers are ginormous. +1 nonetheless

Answer (score 4):

Slip joint pliers can do the job quite well, but I usually use a pair of Vice Grips. There is, however a tool made for this. Here's an image of one:

[image]

It's called a: [Spring Clamp - Flexible Ratchet Tool](http://www.hcl-clamping.com/Spring-Clamp-Flexible-Ratchet-Tool-P40)